Multiple Blazor interactive server apps: webSocket failed to connect
I created a second Blazor interactive server application but after I deploy this to my Linux server, I see these errors in the console:
WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxx.xxx.xx/_blazor?id=nlZ9fewU1Qya1Gxg_if2Uw' failed:

and
Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled. 

But the interactivity of my application does seem to work.
The problems also seem to have started after deploying the second app.
I think that both applications (running on the same IP but different ports) are having trouble to establish the websocket connections. Is there a way to hardcode the ports for the websockets or any solutions for deploying multiple interactive server apps to the same Linux machine?
Thanks a lot!
